# How to get all the pins/markers in on click of a markercluster in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api to create a store locator with clusters and I am referring the [marker cluster api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js).

I wanted to get the list of stores with in a markercluster rather than returning marker cluster with pins/markers. Please find the below code -

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mapsCore.mapsVar.markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
            var content = "";

            // Convert lat/long from cluster object to a usable MVCObject
            var info = new google.maps.MVCObject;
            info.set('position', cluster.center_);
            //----
            //Get markers
            console.log(cluster.getSize());
            var markers = cluster.getMarkers();
            var x = {};
            $(mapsCore.mapsVar.totalResults.Result).each(function(k, v) {
                $(markers).each(function(km, vm) {
                    if (parseFloat(v.LAT) == parseFloat(markers[km].position.lat()) && parseFloat(v.LON) == parseFloat(markers[km].position.lng())) {
                        // locArr[k] = { lat: parseFloat(v.CounterLatitude), lng: parseFloat(v.CounterLongitude) };
                        x.Counter_ID = v.Counter_ID;
                        x.Counter_Name = v.Counter_Name;
                        x.Counter_Zip_code = v.Counter_Zip_code;
                        x.Address_1 = v.Address_1;
                        x.Address_2 = v.Address_2;
                        x.Province = v.Province;
                        x.City = v.City;
                        x.Area = v.Area;
                        x.SubArea = v.SubArea;
                        x.Counter_Tel = v.Counter_Tel;
                        x.Counter_Email = v.Counter_Email;
                        x.Open_Time = v.Open_Time;
                        x.Close_Time = v.Close_Time;
                        x.LAT = v.LAT;
                        x.LON = v.LON;
                        x.MR_FLG = v.MR_FLG;
                        mapsCore.mapsVar.clusterDetail.Results.push(x);
                        x = {};
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Just to clarify for myself, when you click on a cluster, you want to get all the data associated with the markers that make up that cluster?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to list all the markers inside cluster

Comment: What's wrong with the code you provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

thanks for your help for formatting my code and comments any way I found the solution for it. I will attach the spinet of code below

google.maps.event.addListener(mapsCore.mapsVar.markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
                var content = '';

```
            // Convert lat/long from cluster object to a usable MVCObject
            var info = new google.maps.MVCObject;
            info.set('position', cluster.center_);
            //----
            //Get markers
            console.log(cluster.getSize());
            var markers = cluster.getMarkers();
            var x = {};
            mapsCore.mapsVar.clusterDetail.Counters.length = 0;
            $(mapsCore.mapsVar.totalResults.Counters).each(function(k, v) {
                $(markers).each(function(km, vm) {
                    console.log(parseFloat(v.CounterLatitude) == parseFloat(vm.position.lat()) && parseFloat(v.CounterLongitude) == parseFloat(vm.position.lng()));
                    if (parseFloat(v.CounterLatitude) == parseFloat(vm.position.lat())) {
                        // locArr[k] = { lat: parseFloat(v.CounterLatitude), lng: parseFloat(v.CounterLongitude) };
                        x.CounterCode = v.CounterCode;
                        x.CounterName = v.CounterName;
                        x.CounterZipCode = v.CounterZipCode;
                        x.AddressLine1 = v.AddressLine1;
                        x.AddressLine2 = v.AddressLine2;
                        x.Province = v.Province;
                        x.City = v.City;
                        x.Area = v.Area;
                        x.SubArea = v.SubArea;
                        x.CounterPhoneNumber = v.CounterPhoneNumber;
                        x.CounterEmailAddress = v.CounterEmailAddress;
                        x.CounterOpenTime = v.CounterOpenTime;
                        x.CounterCloseTime = v.CounterCloseTime;
                        x.CounterLatitude = v.CounterLatitude;
                        x.CounterLongitude = v.CounterLongitude;
                        x.IsMagicRingAvailable = v.IsMagicRingAvailable;
                        mapsCore.mapsVar.clusterDetail.Counters.push(x);
                        x = {};
                    }
                });
            });
            console.log(mapsCore.mapsVar.clusterDetail);
            var template = $.templates("#mapslist");
            var output = template.render(mapsCore.mapsVar.clusterDetail);
            $(".store-list-section").html(output);
        });
```

Always need to reset the array of object like -

mapsCore.mapsVar.clusterDetail.Counters.length = 0;

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can set a custom image to an transparent png and text size to 0, that way it'll be invisible on the map.

```
cluster.setStyles({
  url: your_path/transparent.png,
  height: 20,
  width: 20,
  textSize: 0
});
```

Alternatively you can try and see if setting the image height and width to 0 works.

Comment: thanks for your code I think you might not have understood my question.